# Issue when responding to a review using the Microsoft Store API (manage.devcenter.microsoft.com)

Tags: uwp, windows-store, windows-dev-center, microsoft-store

For 1.5-2 years we have been using the Microsoft Store API to respond to user reviews on our apps: [Get app reviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-app-reviews),
[Get response info for reviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-response-info-for-app-reviews) and [Submit responses to reviews](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/submit-responses-to-app-reviews). But, 6-7 days ago, this API stopped working properly (as described in the documentation).

Now, when trying to get the status of the review (whether it's possible to respond to it), the API throws a 400 Bad Request error without a body. Sample request and response (identifiers and token replaced with placeholder):

```
GET https://manage.devcenter.microsoft.com/v1.0/my/reviews/{reviewId}/apps/{appId}/responses/info HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Accept: */*
Host: manage.devcenter.microsoft.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 0
MS-CorrelationId: bb9d3b90-936b-4a1a-be8f-28d0a59d2135
MS-RequestId: 7496bf73-b741-40d2-b358-c1a8cf448c17
MS-CV: lNVnuLCqhEaebqWz.0
MS-ServerId: 000007
Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2023 17:45:51 GMT
```

Also, a request to respond to user feedback always sends a 400 Bad Reqest with an error in the body regardless of identifiers:

```
POST https://manage.devcenter.microsoft.com/v1.0/my/reviews/responses HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Host: manage.devcenter.microsoft.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 530

{
    "Responses": [
    {
      "ApplicationId": "{ApplicationId}",
      "ReviewId": "{ReviewId}",
      "ResponseText": "Hello! Thanks for choosing our App! It`s very important for us to know your opinion. E-mail - support@test.com",
      "SupportEmail": "support@test.com",
      "IsPublic": true
    }
  ]
}
```

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
MS-CorrelationId: 2ac6a44c-5ba4-4617-8da1-35d97e8e1410
MS-RequestId: a2479ef3-e4b0-4bb7-8474-110ab4689e19
MS-CV: QRacfg2cJkyisRkt.0
MS-ServerId: 00000G
Date: Mon, 20 Mar 2023 17:55:54 GMT

{"code":4012,"description":"Description: The response is not in the correct format, or some parameter which is required is missing., Exception: ","data":[],"source":"ReviewResponseFD"}
```

At the same time, the request for receiving the list of reviews on our app works well.
Our partners and colleagues from other publishers faced similar problems.
The software implementation (.NET) of these requests gives the same results as above.

Comment: Since this is related to the Store API and it seems to be an issue related to the Store backend. Please open a free support ticket here: **[Contact Us](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support)**. Go to **Contact us** tab , find **Non-Technical Support - Dashboard** and choose **SUBMIT AN INCIDENT**. You could talk to the store team directly and confirm this behavior. The store team could check the status of your account in the back end.